# Dynamic splitting the sitemaps

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I haved followed this [guide](http://www.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/2008/writing-dynamic-xml-sitemaps-using-php/) to create a dynamic XML sitemap. Which includes fetching records from the database & generating a XML out of the URL in the database. But I need to expand this & create a sitemap index whenever the XML gets larger than 10MB or excess of 50,000 URLs. Below is the code that I am using.

```
header ("Content-type: text/xml");
echo ("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n");
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">

    <? while($current_post = mysql_fetch_array($blogs)) { ?>
      <url>
         <loc><?= $current_post[url]) ?></loc>
         <lastmod><?= gmdate(DATE_ATOM, $current_post[timestamp]) ?></lastmod>
      </url>
   <? } ?>
</urlset>
```

Any help or guide to split this & join to a sitemapindex when URL count exceeds 50,000 or file size gets larger thank 10MB will be very helpful. Thanks. Figured maybe dividing the total records by 50,000 would get the number of sitemap_index files required. But still having trouble with splitting it by 10MB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` to get the record count, and output a sitemap index with locations (loc) like `http://www.domain.tld/sitemap.php?offset=50000`. In the single requests for the parts use the [LIMIT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) clause in you MySQL statement.

For the 10MB Limit in a dynamically generated sitemap, I suggest calculating the maximum size of one element and use this as a limit for the record count in a sitemap.

I don't think here is a good way to enforce the 10MB Limit without pregenerating the sitemap files (cronjob). In a cronjob you could start generating the first index file and store how many bytes/elements you have written. If one of this numbers is to large start the next file. Store all generated files in an array, use the array to write the index file.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But splitting by 50,000 isn't the only problem. I need to split by 50,000 but if the file size reaches over 10MB before 50,000 the file should split up as well. any ideas..?

Comment: Updated with cronjob suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the new suggestion. What do you think about mb_strlen($xmlcont, 'UTF-8'). If I loop through the URLs & append the xml to a string variable. I could check the mb_strlen before the next iteration. If this produces a value over 10MB I will split from there. Do you think that this will be a good solution or an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Not really. The problem is that you need to know how many sitemaps with which offsets do you have. If the next offset is only known after you generated one or more 10MB outputs, you get a massive memory and performance problem.

Comment: thanks. I will use your earlier suggestion which involves getting the maximum size of one element and using it as the limit. cronjob requires additional work I have limited time. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of counting how much bytes will take 0-50000 records (& next on) you should get 0-30000, a safer limit, a file containing 30000 URLs will be of 5-7 MB size.

Sitemap of 5-7 MB size is good as it will not overload your Servers.
Also, you can zip the sitemap files (at least for Google).